# Joomla Drop-Down menu on user3. What is the best way to implement a drop-down menu on Joomla?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Now I'm able to create joomla templates (even this last one that is giving me some headache, but the problem is with IE6 and the css...) and then comes the question how do I create a drop-down menu without installing a module and/or component?

actually that is not only my problem! there are a lot of people asking the same thing all over the internet... for the time being, I have no experience with javascript, and will take me some time to get used to CSS before a go deeper into the matrix of web apps and so on...

so, is there and easy to implement drop-down menu "framework" that will work with the joomla menu system to create a drop-down menu?

because I'm not willing to create a flash menu at all, it is fancy on user side, bandwidth, loading time, and finally it's not dynamic!

Just need to say something else! I love this website, I'm a beginner, but not long enought I'll be giving some answers! (gave 2 already about centralization on CSS and IE6 text-aline:center; issue!)

Answer (score 0):

Well you shoud try to use an extension, it's easy and a way better! there are tons of good dropdown menus for joomla why not simply use one of them?

Answer (score 0):

RokNavMenu is a really good extension.  They have drop-down and override support as well as cross browser compatibility out of the box.  I would install it and check it out.

[RokNavMenu in the Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/9020)